# Improvement on anagram search

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is if it is possible to improve this codes such that the words inside my
defined word list can be searched through the entire word_list.txt file faster. I am told that there is a way to do this by iterating through the file once for all 14 words by putting it in an appropriate data structure.

```
word_list = ['serve','rival','lovely','caveat','devote',\
         'irving','livery','selves','latvian','saviour',\
         'observe','octavian','dovetail','Levantine']

def sorted_word(word):
    """This return the sorted word"""
    list_chars = list(word)
    list_chars.sort()
    word_sort = ''.join(list_chars)
    return word_sort

print("Please wait for a few moment...")
print()

#Create a empty dictionary to store our word and the anagrams
dictionary = {}
for words in word_list:
    value = [] #Create an empty list for values for the key
    individual_word_string = words.lower()

    for word in open ('word_list.txt'):
        word1 = word.strip().lower() #Use for comparing

        #When sorted words are the same, update the dictionary        
        if sorted_word(individual_word_string) == sorted_word(word1):
            if word1[0] == 'v':
                value.append(word.strip()) #Print original word in word_list
                tempDict = {individual_word_string:value}
                dictionary.update(tempDict)

#Print dictionary
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    print("{:<10} = {:<}".format(key,value))
```

Because of new user restriction, I couldn't post the image of my result. And by the way, the result is supposed to print out anagrams that start with v for each word. Will be glad for any help to improve this code.

Comment: you can sort the word simply as `word = ''.join(sorted(word))` instead of a function

Comment: You might want to begin by swapping your two loops around -- the outer loop iterating over the words in the file, and your inner loop comparing it against your word list.

Comment: I see that would make more sense too. Thanks

Comment: Do not use those backslashes to continue a line. Python automatically continues lines between `()`, `[]` and `{}`. In general never ever use the backslash line continuation. If you have to continue a line then add parentheses around it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough memory you can try storing values into a dictionary and then perform an hash search over it (quite fast). The nice thing about this is that you can pickle it to use it again in the future (the process of dict creating is slow, the lookup is fast).
If you have incredibly big datasets you might want to use map reduce, disco-project is a nice python/erlang framework that I suggest.

```
word_list = ['serve','rival','lovely','caveat','devote',\
         'irving','livery','selves','latvian','saviour',\
         'observe','octavian','dovetail','Levantine']

print("Please wait for a few moment...")
print()

anagrams = {}

for word in open ('word_list.txt'):
    word = word.strip().lower() #Use for comparing
    key = tuple(sorted(word))
    anagrams[key] = anagrams.get(key,[]) + [word]

for word in word_list:
    print "%s -> %s" % (word.lower(),aragrams[tuple(sorted(word.lower()))])
```